# How to click the mouse buttons with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, shortcut-menu

I have an application without keyboard shortcuts where I have to do a recursive work, in practice I have to insert fields with keyboard and click the mouse button over the `OK`button so I have to switch between keyboard and mouse very often only to click without moving the mouse. I know that in `System Preference->Acessibility` I can enable mouse keys but if I have to press `alt`five times before I can use the mouse and then I can't no more type with the keyboard until I disable the mouse keys I lose more time then the first solution.

Put the mouse in the floor and press the button with the foot's finger is an alternative but other users may not approve it. How can I set a quick short-cut for clicking with mouse pointer from keyboard in mac Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToPointingButton__ KeyCode::F1, PointingButton::LEFT</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can do this with the following macro:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [this help](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11263) from Apple's support page.
I hope it solves your problem. ;)

Comment: Thanks but this is the solution I mentioned in the question, I can't write with the keyboard if I enable the mouse keys in this way so it is slower then the first solution...

Comment: It's useful if your keyboard has numeric keypad, so that you'll be able to write with keyboard at the same time.

Comment: Ok, you are right maybe if I had a numercipad I can use this,please write this in the answer for the other users...Thanks